# C# Sharepoint Get current user under whitch code running

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint

I have code from tutorial, code running on WCF service under DOMAIN\AppPoolAccount

But code except that Access Denied, how determinate user?

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://portal.local"))
            {
                SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);


                UserProfileManager userProfileMgr = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
                ProfilePropertyManager profilePropMgr = new UserProfileConfigManager(serviceContext).ProfilePropertyManager;

                // Retrieve all properties for the "UserProfile" profile subtype,
                // and retrieve the property values for a specific user.
                ProfileSubtypePropertyManager subtypePropMgr = profilePropMgr.GetProfileSubtypeProperties("UserProfile");
                UserProfile userProfile = userProfileMgr.GetUserProfile(accountName);
                IEnumerator<ProfileSubtypeProperty> userProfileSubtypeProperties = subtypePropMgr.GetEnumerator();
                while (userProfileSubtypeProperties.MoveNext())
                {
                    string propName = userProfileSubtypeProperties.Current.Name;
                    ProfileValueCollectionBase values = userProfile.GetProfileValueCollection(propName);
                    if (values.Count > 0)
                    {

                        // Handle multivalue properties.
                        foreach (var value in values)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(propName + ": " + value.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(propName + ": ");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to change the values.");
                Console.Read();

                // Change the value of a single-value user property.
                userProfile[PropertyConstants.Department].Value = "SDDDD";
                userProfile.Commit();


            }
```

How determinate user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SPWeb.CurrentUser property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.currentuser(v=office.15).aspx) to determine the current user:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        var currentUser = web.CurrentUser;
        //..

    }
}
```

Comment: currentUser is null its mean Anonymous?